# Resizing attribute form in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, fields-attributes, mac

I am working in QGIS 3.4.11 on macOS 10.14.6.

For a polygonal vector layer, I have a simple autogenerated attributes form in QGIS. Every time I add a new feature in the layer, the attributes form that appears is so small, so I need to resize it. Any ideas on how to change it?

Here is how it looks when I press right mouse button after creating a feature:

[image: example1]

And here is the resized form that I'd like to have by default.

[image: example2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open Layer properties - Attributes form - switch from Autogenerate to Drag and drop designer (worked for me).

[image: Layer properties Attributes Form tab]

Comment: This workaround worked for me too, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is a known bug: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29223.

It's Mac-specific, and may be related to a similar issue with the Identify results window. It doesn't look like anyone is working on a fix at the moment. See [the issue tracker page on github](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/29223) for more details and up-to-date information.

github user [emonshaugen](https://github.com/emonshaugen) suggested this workaround:

> When you create a new feature, and the Attribute Form pop-up appears, you can hit the green (+) symbol to maximize the dialogue box. From then on (until you shut your project down) the dialogue box will pop-up full screen.